# Joomla: Customize FB open graph meta for specific pages

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-opengraph

I need to add the FB meta tags in some pages which are not articles. I need also for a multilingual purpose.

I looked at `http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions ... open-graph` but I didn't find the extensions which respond to my requirement.

I have urls like:

```
index.php?option=com_mycomponent&lang=en

index.php?option=com_mycomponent&lang=fr

index.php?option=com_mycomponent&lang=es
```

And of course, each description or title must be different because of language when visitors share this page.

Does anyone already fix this kind of problem?

If it doesn't exist any extension to manage that, where should I add them in the code? The views page are for the content part. Where is located the header of the page of a joomla component?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own custom tags in Joomla using **[JDocument/setMetaData](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/setMetaData)** method.

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMetaData( 'tag-name', 'tag-content' );
```

As for language detection, you could use: **[JFactory/getLanguage](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getLanguage)** method.

```
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();
```

So an example of your final code could be:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
if( $lang->getTag() == "en-GB") { // getTag() returns language tag
   $doc->setMetaData( "og:title", "English title" );
} else {
   $doc->setMetaData( "og:title", "Title for other languages" );
}
```

If you need information about open graph meta tags usage, you could check facebook developers site: **[Use proper Open Graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)**.